# Remote developing with Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

My project files is in a remote(ftp/svn) server
How to develop the project direct in the remote server? just like a local dir ?
can do that with Xcode ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge difference between an ftp server and a subversion server.  Assuming subversion, since no one in their right mind would use ftp for hosting development work these days (seriously -- it is a gigantic pile of insecurity and cannot offer anything akin to a real filesystem experience).

So, with subversion, check out your code from the svn server to your local filesystem, do you development work, and periodically check your changes back in.  In this, doing development with Xcode works just like any other subversion based development workflow.

Or you can use the rather-good-and-always-improving subversion client interface in Xcode itself.  See the SCM menu.